# Sufficient condition for invertibility for $ \mathbf{w}^Tf(\mathbf{z}) = \alpha + \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{u}h(\alpha + b) $?

Tags: calculus

Suppose $\mathbf{z}, \mathbf{w}, \mathbf{u}\in\mathbb{R}^D, \alpha, b\in\mathbb{R}^1$ and $h(\cdot)$ is any smooth, element-wise function, e.g. tanh. And $f(\cdot)$ is any function.

Given the following equation

$$ \mathbf{w}^Tf(\mathbf{z}) = \alpha + \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{u}h(\alpha + b) $$

where $\mathbf{z} = \alpha\frac{\mathbf{w}}{\Vert\mathbf{w}\Vert^2}$.

it is said the sufficient condition for the equation to be invertible w.r.t $\alpha$ is the right hand side to be a non-decreasing function, i.e. $1 + \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{u}h'(\alpha + b) \ge 0$.

I am confused why it must be case that the right hand side is non-decreasing in order to invert for $\alpha$ ?

Comment: Is the right side regarded as a function of $b$?

Comment: @coffeemath No, it can be regarded as a function of $\alpha$

Comment: Then in $\mathbb{R}^D,$ if $D>1,$ what is the meaning of nondecreasing? Also now there is no $z$ on the right side.

Comment: @coffeemath I've updated the problem, the $\mathbf{z}$ is canceled out by inner product with $\mathbf{w}$

Comment: @coffeemath Non-decreasing is w.r.t. $\alpha$, mathematically, $1 + \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{u}h'(\alpha + b) \ge 0$

Comment: The right side could also be non-decreasing and still get one-to one.  That a (strictly) increasing real function has an inverse is a fairly standard fact.

Comment: @coffeemath Do you mean something [like this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Strictly_Monotone_Function)

Comment: Exactly, Xingdong...